# Scheme Scoping (define and let)

Tags: scheme, scoping, racket

So I know that in Scheme define is for dynamic scoping and let for static scoping, yet the following thing confuses me:

If I have

```
(let ((x 0))
  (define f (lambda () x))
  (display (f))
  (let ((x 1))
    (display (f))
    )
  )
```

It will display 00. So far so good. However, if I add an extra define for x like so:

```
(let ((x 0))
  (define f (lambda () x))
  (display (f))
  (define x 4)
  (let ((x 1))
    (display (f))
    )
  )
```

It will display undefined4. Why is this? Why does defining x **after** evaluating f affect the returned value of (f)? And why is the return value "undefined"?

It is also worth mentioning that binding f with letrec instead of define will also work:

```
(let ((x 0))
  (letrec ((f (lambda () x)))
  (display (f))
  (define x 4)
  (let ((x 1))
    (display (f))
    )
  )
)
```

Returns 00.

Note: I have used DrRacket with the languge set on "Pretty Big"

Comment: What do you mean by "define is for dynamic scoping in Scheme" ? BTW, unless you are required to use it for a course, "Pretty Big" is an obsolete dialect.

Comment: Scheme always uses static scoping, it's incorrect to state that "define is for dynamic and let for static scoping"

Comment: I agree with Oscar: the premise in the question is either wrong, or is using the wrong term.

Comment: Define allows dynamic scoping. Look at the following example:
(define x 1)
(define f (lambda() x))
(display (f))
(define x 2)
(display (f))
Displays 12
As oposed to:

(let ((x 1))
  (letrec ((f (lambda() x)))
    (display (f))
    (let ((x 2))
      (display (f))
      )
    )
  )
which displays 11

Comment: @user2085086: no, you are confusing the effect of two toplevel defines, the second of which is *re-assigning* the first.  In some implementations of Scheme, redefinition will be treated as a `set!`.  But this is troublesome and confusing.  In fact, your first code snippet won't even compile in standard Racket, as the compiler will say up front that the duplicate definition is illegal.

Answer (score 6):

The issue you're experiencing in the second case is that `(define x 42)` makes `x` a variable for the *entire* scope in which it's defined. Now, although the *variable* is defined for the entire scope, its *value* is undefined until the actual `(define x 42)` line.

```
(let ()
  ;; up here, `x` is defined but has an undefined value
  ;; ...
  (define x 42)
  ;; down here `x` has the value 42
  ;; ...
  )
```

It's acting more like this:

```
(let ([x 'undefined])
  ;; ... up here, `x` is 'undefined
  (set! x 42)
  ;; ... down here, `x` is 42
  )
```

Comment: Bun where goes `let ((x 0))` at the top?

Answer (score 1):

Your second and third code snippets are not Scheme (none of R5RS, R6RS nor R7RS).  The `<body>` (of a `let` and others) is defined as:

```
<body> -> <definition>* <sequence>
<sequence> -> <command>* <expression>
<command> -> <expression>
```

and thus a `define` (which is a `<definition>`) **cannot** follow `display` (an `<expression>`).  You are likely getting confusing results because the compiler/interpreter is incorrectly handling the expansion of 'let'.

Here is what a 'good' R6RS compiler does:

```
> (let ((x 0))
  (letrec ((f (lambda () x)))
  (display (f))
  (define x 4)
  (let ((x 1))
    (display (f))
    )
  )
)
Unhandled exception
 Condition components:
   1. &who: define
   2. &message: "a definition was found where an expression was expected"
   3. &syntax:
       form: (define x 4)
       subform: #f
   4. &trace: #<syntax (define x 4)>
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: the body of f binds to the outermost let in both invocations, resulting in 00 as static scope requires.

Case 2: I'm not very sure about this, but the internal `(define x 4)` shadows the outermost x=0 binding, and is in scope throughout even though it's textually after the call to f. Then some order of evaluation trickiness makes the first call happen before the new x binding is fully initialized, so it's "uninitialized". The second call in the inner let happens after everything is initialized, so 4.

Case 3: Now that we have explicitly put the letrec and the define in separate scopes, f obviously refers to the outermost let. The define does nothing here.